# UIDatePicker, setting maximum and minimum dates based on day names and todays date

Tags: iphone, swift, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker, and I wish to set the minimum and maximum date range to be between Thursday to Wednesday of the current week, how would I set that up?
picker date is the date picker and datepicker text field is text field

```
pickerDate.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
datePickerTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(pickerDate.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

- Create an instance of `NSCalendar`
- Create the date components (including `NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear` from the current date using the calendar
- Create date components with the desired values for `NSCalendarUnit.Weekday`
- Use calendar to calculate the dates from the date components

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[comps setDay: -7];
NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];

[datePicker setMaximumDate:currentDate];
[datePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```